Generating HLS TS Segments with C#
H264 File Sample
Example Source Code
At the end of my message, you will find the code for my sample project, an example h264 elementary stream file, and a screen output. The aim of this sample project is to stream data read from an h264 file as HLS (HTTP Live Stream).
I've written parts such as handling requests and generating playlists. However, I haven't been able to fully implement the segment generation (TS) part. I theoretically understand how it should be done, but there are too many different concepts involved. For example, creating 188-byte packets and adding some headers or footers, etc.
My ultimate goal is to serve h264 elementary stream data obtained from RTSP as HLS. Therefore, I don't even need to support all formats. As you know, h264 data consists of SPS, PPS, IFrame, PFrame data separated by the 0x00 00 00 01 NAL Unit.
In fact, there are projects written in Go that accomplish this task, but I need to do it in C#. As you can see in the screenshots I shared below, the data transferred with the code written inside GetBytes can be watched with ffplay (ffplay http://localhost:8080/stream.m3u8).
However, I am fully aware that this is not the correct approach. The GetBytes (or GetNextSegment which calls GetBytes) method should generate the TS segments I mentioned earlier. As it is, it cannot be played in VLC player or internet browsers.
In the code I shared below, I would like to draw your attention to the H264FileToHLSServer.cs file.
I am requesting your help on this matter.

How should I approach the source data in the GetSegment method? Should I read it frame by frame, as fixed-length byte blocks, or in SPS, PPS blocks?
How should I generate TS segments? What is the algorithm for this?

Preferably, I would like to solve this issue by writing plain code in C#. However, I am also open to solutions using the ffplay.Autogen C# library or by pinvoking the Microsoft MPEG-2 encoder. I am sharing the entire code below. I hope I can get some help this time. Thank you in advance.
Starting the server and calling it with ffplay:

Result with the ffplay:

Here is my code:
Program.cs:
var trace = (string message) => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff") + ": " + message);

var options = new FBCHLSServerOptions(8080, false)
{
    LLPartTarget = .5f,
    //LowLatencySupport = false,
    //Port = 8080,
    SegmentDuration = 4,
    SegmentBufferCount = 5,
    SourceFPS = 2,
    SegmentRequestType = HLSSegmentRequestType.TS,
};

trace("Starting server...:");

//File path: d:\a\0_240p_2fps.264
var server = new H264FileToHLSServer(@"d:\a\0_240p_2fps.264", options);

server.OnTrace += (s, e) => trace(e);
server.Start();
trace("Server started. Press any key to stop.");

// http://localhost:8080/stream.m3u8
trace($"URL: http://localhost:{options.Port}/stream.m3u8");
Console.ReadKey();
server.Stop();
server.Dispose();
trace("Bye!");

FBCHLSServerOptions:
public enum HLSSegmentRequestType
{
    TS,
    M4S,
}

public class FBCHLSServerOptions
{
    public int Port { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Low latency support
    /// </summary>
    public bool LowLatencySupport { get; set; }
    public int SourceFPS { get; set; } = 25;
    /// <summary>
    /// Segment duration in seconds
    /// </summary>
    public int SegmentDuration { get; set; } = 4;
    /// <summary>
    /// Segment buffer count. Meaning how many segments will be sent to client for each request
    /// </summary>
    public int SegmentBufferCount { get; set; } = 5;
    /// <summary>
    /// Low latency part target. This is the part of the segment that will be sent to client. Default is .5
    /// </summary>
    public float LLPartTarget { get; set; } = .5f;

    public HLSSegmentRequestType SegmentRequestType { get; set; } = HLSSegmentRequestType.TS;

    public FBCHLSServerOptions(int port, bool lowLatencySupport)
    {
        Port = port;
        LowLatencySupport = lowLatencySupport;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //Json with intended and with enum as string
        return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(this,
            new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                WriteIndented = true,
                Converters = { new System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter()
                }
            });
    }
}

H264FileToHLSServer.cs:
public class H264FileToHLSServer : FBCHLSServerBase, IDisposable
{
    private readonly string filePath;
    private FileStream? fileStream;

    public H264FileToHLSServer(string filePath, FBCHLSServerOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        InitializeFileStream();
    }

    private void InitializeFileStream()
    {
        try
        {
            fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace($"Error initializing file stream: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: I know this part shouldn't be like this, but I don't know how to make Mpeg 2 TS.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="frames"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private byte[] GetBytes(int frames)
    {
        if (fileStream == null)
        {
            InitializeFileStream();
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[frames * 1024];
        var read = fileStream!.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        if (read == 0)
        {
            fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        return buffer.Take(read).ToArray();
    }

    public override byte[] GetInitSegment()
    {
        return GetBytes(1);
    }

    public override byte[] GetNextPart(int frames)
    {
        return GetBytes(frames);
    }

    public override byte[] GetNextSegment(int frames)
    {
        return GetBytes(frames);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        fileStream?.Dispose();
    }
}

FBCHLSServerBase.cs:
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

public abstract class FBCHLSServerBase
{
    int segmentIndex = 1;
    int partIndex = 0; // Added for LL-HLS part tracking
    object lockObj = new object();
    HttpListener? listener;
    FBCHLSServerOptions options;

    public event EventHandler<string>? OnTrace;

    protected void Trace(string message)
    {
        OnTrace?.Invoke(this, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ": " + message);
    }

    public FBCHLSServerBase(FBCHLSServerOptions options)
    {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://localhost:{options.Port}/");
        listener.Start();
        listener.BeginGetContext(OnRequest, null);
        Trace("Options: " + options.ToString());
        Trace($"Server started on port {options.Port}");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            if (listener != null)
            {
                listener.Stop();
                listener.Close();
                listener = null;
            }
        }
        Trace("Server stopped");
    }

    private void OnRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Trace("OnRequest");
        HttpListenerContext context;

        lock (lockObj)
        {
            if (listener == null) return;
            context = listener.EndGetContext(ar);
            listener.BeginGetContext(OnRequest, null);
        }

        try
        {
            //Veriyi gönderirken eğer clienti kapatırsak hata alıyoruz. Bu yüzden try catch içerisine aldık.
            HandleRequest(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace("Error on Handling Request: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void SetHeader(HttpListenerContext context, byte[] content, bool isM3U8, bool isMp4)
    {
        /*
            Accept-Ranges                 : bytes
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers  : origin, range
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods  : GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin   : *
            Access-Control-Expose-Headers : Server,range
            Content-Length                : 14093
            Content-Type                  : application/vnd.apple.mpegurl

            Date: Mon, 03 Jun 2024 21:10:56 GMT
            Etag: "usp-E130F796"
            Last-Modified: Mon, 21 Jun 2021 14:30:27 GMT
            Server: Apache/2.4.58 (Unix)
            X-Usp: version=1.13.0 (29687)
         */
        context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, range");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Server,range");
        //context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", content.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.ContentLength64 = content.Length;

        if (isM3U8)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl";
        }
        else
        {
            if (isMp4)
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "video/MP2T";
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        string url = context.Request.Url!.AbsolutePath;
        Trace($"Request for {url}");

        if (url.EndsWith("/stream.m3u8"))
        {
            Trace("Sending M3U8 playlist");
            string m3u8Content = GenerateM3U8Playlist();
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m3u8Content);
            SetHeader(context, buffer, true, false);
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Trace("M3U8 playlist sent");
        }
        else if (url.EndsWith("init.mp4"))
        {
            Trace("Sending init segment");
            byte[] initSegment = GetInitSegment();
            context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = initSegment.Length;
            context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // CORS için ekleme
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(initSegment, 0, initSegment.Length);
            Trace("Init segment sent");
        }
        else if (url.EndsWith(".ts"))
        {
            Trace("Sending TS segment");
            byte[] segment = GetNextSegment(options.SourceFPS * options.SegmentDuration);
            context.Response.ContentType = "video/MP2T";
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = segment.Length;
            context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // CORS için ekleme
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(segment, 0, segment.Length);
            Trace("TS segment sent");
        }
        else if (url.EndsWith(".m4s"))
        {
            Trace("Sending M4S segment");
            byte[] segment = GetNextSegment(options.SourceFPS * options.SegmentDuration);
            context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = segment.Length;
            context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // CORS için ekleme
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(segment, 0, segment.Length);
            Trace("M4S segment sent");
        }
        else if (options.LowLatencySupport && url.EndsWith(".part"))
        {
            Trace("Sending LL-HLS part");
            byte[] part = GetNextPart((int)(options.SourceFPS * options.LLPartTarget));

            if (options.SegmentRequestType == HLSSegmentRequestType.M4S)
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
            }
            else if (options.SegmentRequestType == HLSSegmentRequestType.TS)
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "video/MP2T";
            }

            context.Response.ContentLength64 = part.Length;
            context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // CORS için ekleme
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(part, 0, part.Length);
            partIndex++; // Increment part index for each part sent
            Trace($"Part {partIndex} sent");
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }

        context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
    }

    private string GetExt(HLSSegmentRequestType segmentRequestType)
    {
        return segmentRequestType == HLSSegmentRequestType.TS ? "ts" : "m4s";
    }

    string GenerateM3U8Playlist()
    {
        StringBuilder m3u8Builder = new StringBuilder();
        m3u8Builder.AppendLine("#EXTM3U");

        // Use version 7 for LL-HLS
        m3u8Builder.AppendLine(options.LowLatencySupport ? "#EXT-X-VERSION:7" : "#EXT-X-VERSION:1");

        m3u8Builder.AppendLine($"#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:{segmentIndex}");
        m3u8Builder.AppendLine($"#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:{options.SegmentDuration}");
        //#USP-X-TIMESTAMP-MAP:MPEGTS=900000,LOCAL=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
        //m3u8Builder.AppendLine("#USP-X-TIMESTAMP-MAP:MPEGTS=900000,LOCAL=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z");

        if (!options.LowLatencySupport)
        {
            /*
             * #EXTINF:4, no desc
             * segment-1.ts
             * #EXTINF:4, no desc
             * segment-2.ts
             * #EXTINF:4, no desc
             * segment-3.ts                 
             */

            for (int i = 0; i < options.SegmentBufferCount; i++)
            {
                int segmentNumber = segmentIndex - (options.SegmentBufferCount - 1 - i);

                if (segmentNumber >= 0)
                {
                    m3u8Builder.AppendLine($"#EXTINF:{options.SegmentDuration}, no desc");
                    m3u8Builder.AppendLine($"segment{segmentNumber}.{GetExt(options.SegmentRequestType)}");
                }
            }
        }

        //if (options.LowLatencySupport)
        //{
        //    m3u8Builder.AppendLine("#EXT-X-MAP:URI=\"init.mp4\"");
        //    m3u8Builder.AppendLine($"#EXT-X-PART-INF:PART-TARGET={options.LLPartTarget}");
        //    m3u8Builder.AppendLine($"#EXT-X-SERVER-CONTROL:CAN-BLOCK-RELOAD=YES,PART-HOLD-BACK={options.LLPartTarget * 3},HOLD-BACK={options.SegmentDuration * 3}");
        //    // Add parts for low latency
        //    for (int i = 0; i < options.SegmentBufferCount; i++)
        //    {
        //        int segmentNumber = segmentIndex - (options.SegmentBufferCount - 1 - i);
        //        if (segmentNumber >= 0)
        //        {
        //            for (int j = 0; j < (int)(options.SegmentDuration / options.LLPartTarget); j++)
        //            {
        //                m3u8Builder.AppendLine($"#EXT-X-PART:DURATION={options.LLPartTarget},INDEPENDENT=YES,URI=\"segment{segmentNumber}_part{j}{(options.SegmentRequestType == HLSSegmentRequestType.TS ? ".part" : ".m4s")}\"");
        //            }
        //            m3u8Builder.AppendLine($"#EXTINF:{options.SegmentDuration},");
        //            m3u8Builder.AppendLine($"segment{segmentNumber}{(options.SegmentRequestType == HLSSegmentRequestType.TS ? ".ts" : ".m4s")}");
        //        }
        //    }
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    m3u8Builder.AppendLine("#EXT-X-MAP:URI=\"init.mp4\"");
        //    // Add segments for standard HLS
        //    for (int i = 0; i < options.SegmentBufferCount; i++)
        //    {
        //        int segmentNumber = segmentIndex - (options.SegmentBufferCount - 1 - i);
        //        if (segmentNumber >= 0)
        //        {
        //            m3u8Builder.AppendLine($"#EXTINF:{options.SegmentDuration},");
        //            m3u8Builder.AppendLine($"segment{segmentNumber}{(options.SegmentRequestType == HLSSegmentRequestType.TS ? ".ts" : ".m4s")}");
        //        }
        //    }
        //}

        //listemiz sonsuz olacak şekilde ayarlanacağı için #EXT-X-ENDLIST eklemiyoruz.
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            segmentIndex++;
        }

        return m3u8Builder.ToString();
    }

    public abstract byte[] GetNextSegment(int frames);
    public abstract byte[] GetNextPart(int frames);
    public abstract byte[] GetInitSegment(); // New method for init segment
}

